# ng-option not being selected from angularjs Select using ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have already checked other solution with same problem but nothing worked.
I am facing issue in selecting the drop down value as per the ng-model. Below is the code I am using -

```
<select class="form-control"  name="adminID" 
    ng-model="hospitalsCtrl.hospital.admin_id" 
    ng-disabled="hospitalsCtrl.hospital.ID" 
    ng-options="admin.ID as admin.email  for admin in  hospitalsCtrl.adminsList  track by admin.ID" required>
    <option value="">Please Choose</option>
</select>
```

Its generating option like below -
 [image: options being generated]

The ng-model value is being populated properly , but the element is not selected.
Please help.

Fiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/6xy03urf/4/

TIA.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this

Comment: Maybe you should add some js here, btw is hospitalsCtrl.hospital defined ?

Comment: Added fiddle, had to add js in the HTML part only,  https://jsfiddle.net/6xy03urf/4/

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO , yes its defined in the controller and I am able to print the value of hospitalsCtrl.hospital.admin_id as well in the output.
You can check the fiddle also, it showing same behaviour.

Comment: what do you mean by "but the element is not selected" ? it seems to work in your sample

Comment: the option element with value as that of hospitalsCtrl.hospital.admin_id  is not selected. Its happening is case of edit, when I load the page for edit , it should select the actual value by default.
In example when you load the page, you can see the default "Admin Id 2", but the corresponding drop down value is not selected in the drop down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the track by admin.ID part from ng-options as it is not allowing to bind with ng-model.
Try below code in your HTML

```
<select class="form-control"  name="adminID" 
    ng-model="hospitalsCtrl.admin_id" 
    ng-options="admin.ID as admin.email  for admin in  hospitalsCtrl.adminsList" required>
    <option value="">Please Choose</option>
</select>
```

In your JS make a little change like below

```
     var app = angular.module('App',[]);
app.controller('Hospitals-Controller', function(){

    console.log("ASA");
    var self = this;

     //self.admin_id = 2 ;

    self.adminsList = [
                    { "ID" : 1,
                "name" : "test 1",
              "email" : "abc@abc.com"

            },
            { "ID" : 2,
                "name" : "test 2",
              "email" : "abc2@abc.com"

            },
             { "ID" : 3,
                "name" : "test 3",
              "email" : "abc3@abc.com"

            }];
                        self.admin_id = self.adminsList[1].ID;
})
```

Here is the [explanation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) from Angular on how to use select as and track by

> Because the selected option has been set programmatically in the
>   controller, the track by expression is also applied to the ngModel
>   value.In the example, the ngModel value is adminsList[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).ID and the
>   track by expression evaluates to adminsList[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).ID.id (which is
>   undefined). As a result, the model value is not matched against any
>    and the  appears as having no selected value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I remove the "track by" , it works in the fiddle but its not working in my app, its exactly the same code.
If I use ng-repeat with options it works fine, so I am sticking with that instead of ng-options.

Comment: No don't use ng-repeat instead of ng-options ! ng-options  has lot of flexibility in case of dropdowns more than ng-repeat.Did you set your ng-model object like I did in answer ?

Comment: you mean the last line ? self.admin_id =  self.adminsList[1].ID ? this is basically setting the ID value which I have already from the DB, but its not selecting the required value.

Comment: Hmm that's hurting :( Okay mate !

Comment: I know right! There are things in angular which are remains unexplained :P :P

Comment: This is perfect !

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
var self = this;

self.adminsList = [
                { "ID" : 1,
            "name" : "test 1",
          "email" : "abc@abc.com"

        },
        { "ID" : 2,
            "name" : "test 2",
          "email" : "abc2@abc.com"

        },
         { "ID" : 3,
            "name" : "test 3",
          "email" : "abc3@abc.com"

        }];

          self.admin_id = self.adminsList[1];
```

Comment: is there any way to select the option on basis of just Id, not whole object?

Comment: why do you want only the id ? this solution don't fit your needs ?

Comment: As  I do not have whole object I just have id for the field.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers provided above are valid , but for some reasons its not working for my app. Using ng-repeat for options instead of ng-options is working for me. Posting the code it might help someone with my situation :P .
Below is the code which worked for me -

```
<select class="form-control"  name="adminID" ng-model="hospitalsCtrl.hospital.admin_id" 
ng-disabled="hospitalsCtrl.hospital.ID" required>
    <option value="">Please Choose</option>
    <option ng-repeat="admin in hospitalsCtrl.adminsList" value="{{admin.ID}}">{{admin.email}}</option>
                        </select>
```